# Change CSS background-color using Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

As the title suggest, I'm trying to change my css background-color using javascript function. To simplify the problem, I write a new code here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Potato</title>

<style>
#item {
    background-color:blue;
    color:red;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeBG(id,color) {
        var id = id;
        var color = color;

        document.getElementById(id).style.background-color = color;
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">changeBG(item,green)</script>
<div id="item">I am a potato</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The default background-color is red (as suggested by CSS), then I want to change it to green before I print it. But the code doesn't work. I don't know where the mistake is.

Comment: A good place to start would be to review your JS tutorial, and bone up on the difference between a variable `green` and a string literal `"green"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `item` needs to be made first:

```
<div id="item">I am a potato</div>
<script>
     //...stuff....
</script>
```

Then we need to use strings:

```
changeBG("item","green")
```

And finally in JavaScript we say `backgroundColor` other than `background-color`.

Answer (score 1):

```
@media print {
   #item {
    background-color:green;
   }
}
```

Include this in your css. This will solves your problem while printing.

Answer (score 0):

All css properties in javascript are camelCased rather than spinal-cased

```
document.getElementById('youElement').style.backgroundColor = 'color';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery

```
$("#item").css("background-color", "green");
```

[Documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css.asp)

Or pure JavaScript

```
document.getElementById("item").style.backgroundColor = "green";
```

[Documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp)